# Covering the entire div's with HTMl divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, division

Supoose the screen size is 1920by1080, then I want div of user input suppose say 200by200

then these div's of this dimensions should create the entire screen. How can i do that using HMTL, CSS and javascript.

**CSS CODE**

```
      div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="enter height of div" id="div_height" />
<input type="number" placeholder="enter width of div" id="div_width" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
      function myFunction() {
    let height_div = document.getElementById('div_height').value;
    let width_div = document.getElementById('div_width').value;
   
    var xy = '',
      i,
      size = 20;

    var x = screen.availHeight;
    var y = screen.availWidth;

    while (x > height_div) {
      while (y > width_div) {
        xy = xy + '<div>' + '</div>';
        y = y - width_div;
      }

      x = x - height_div;
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = xy;
    console.log(height_div + ' ' + width_div);
document.getElementsByTagName('div').style.height = height_div + 'px';
document.getElementsByTagName('div').style.width = width_div + 'px';
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific what you want or what is your actual status or the design you need to implement.
Without any information or img it is hard to help.

Comment: ADDED CODE PLS REVIEW

Comment: In your image the divs aren't 200 x 200 ?

Comment: giving you an idea how it looks

Comment: include better keywords in your title like available screen grid height width pixels calculate

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
div
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Then it would cover entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let height_div = document.getElementById("div_height").value;
  let width_div = document.getElementById("div_width").value;

  var xy = "";

  const xi = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / width_div);
  const yi = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / height_div);

  for (let i = 0; i < yi; i++) {
    xy += "<div class='row'>";
    for (let j = 0; j < xi; j++) {
      xy += "<div></div>"
    }
    xy += '</div>'
  }
  console.log(xy)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xy;
  console.log(height_div + " " + width_div);
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).map(el => (el.style.height = height_div + "px"));
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).map(el => (el.style.width = width_div + "px"));
}
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', myFunction);
```

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-style: solid;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

p#demo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="number" placeholder="enter height of div" id="div_height" />
  <input type="number" placeholder="enter width of div" id="div_width" />
  <button>Try it</button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Try something like this,
you can use `Math.ceiling` if you want to fill the white gaps and have a little hangover